# How to scale image correctly for Android app?

Tags: android, image, scale, android-imageview

I don't understand how to scale images correctly in android.
I have a picture for an iPhone app that's 640*125 pixels. I need to use this in
an Android app but i don't get how to scale it correct.

In the image below I use 'FitEnd' as ScaleType, this looks OK apart from the height which is
 approximately twice the size it should be (it should only be as high as the highest part of the grey figure).

How do I fix this?

[image: Selection shows the image i need to scale]

Edit: including .xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ViewFlipper
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonrow" >

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/flipper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    layout="@layout/activity_events" />
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    layout="@layout/event_detail" />
            </ViewFlipper>  
            <include
                android:id="@+id/second"
                layout="@layout/event_detail" />
        </ViewFlipper>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonrow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:src="@drawable/bottombar" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two versions:

1. the image has non-transparent background. So the image params are okey, the problem is in your picture
2. if not the first version, than show me please your .xml file

Comment: The image has transparent background, I have edited my post and included the .xml file.